# Polars group_by_dynamic to only include complete downsample periods

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

Consider the following 1-minute dataframe:

```
start_dt = datetime(2023,11,30,7,00)
end_dt = datetime(2023,11,30,7,11)

df_1 = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'date': pl.datetime_range(start_dt, end_dt, interval='1m', eager=True),
        'open': 1,
        'close': 2
    }
)
```

It can be downsampled, with Polars, as follows:

```
df_5 = (
    df_1
    .group_by_dynamic('date', every='5m')
    .agg(
        pl.col('open').first(),
        pl.col('close').last()
    )
)
```

Resulting in:

```
date    open    close
datetime[μs]    i64 i64
2023-11-30 07:00:00 1   2
2023-11-30 07:05:00 1   2
2023-11-30 07:10:00 1   2
```

The 07:00 period includes 1-minute periods 07:00 to 07:04.

The 07:05 period includes 1-minute periods 07:05 to 07:09.

However, the 07:10 period can only include the 1-minute periods 07:10 to 07:11 because that is where the 1-minute periods end.

I need to instruct group_by_dynamic that it should end on a 5-minute period that includes the last expected minute from the 1-minute data.

In other words, for the 5-minute 07:10 period to be complete, it would have needed to see the 07:14 period in the 1-minute data. But, because that period was not present, I only want it to downsample up to 07:05.

Can anyone suggest an elegant way to achieve this please?

**Edit:**
Please note that, in a real situation, it cannot be guaranteed that there will be data every 1-minute. This means that some valid 5-minute periods will consist of less than 5 x 1-minute periods.

For example, if there were periods: 07:00, 07:03, 07:05, 07:06, it would be fine to generate a 5-minute 07:00 period consisting of just 07:00, 07:03 because the presence of a period at 07:05 informs us it must be complete. However, it should not include a 5-minute period, at 07:05, because there is insufficient data to inform us that the period is actually complete.

Comment: Can you calculate the diff inside `.agg()` and filter afterwards? e.g. `diff = pl.last("date") - pl.first("date")`

Comment: Please see my comment on the answer below.

Comment: You should edit your question so that it's clear that you don't really have regular intervals as you say at the beginning of your question. I deleted my answer so not everyone can see those comments.

Comment: Ah right, so if the "next group" exists the current group is valid. Seems like maybe you would need to start with `df.with_columns(group=pl.col("date").dt.truncate("5m")` - then check the final group.

Comment: What should happen in cases where data for an entire group is missing, but the "next group" exists?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that

- each group contains at least one row, and
- a group is considered *valid* if the last possible data row within the group exists or there is a "next group".

A tentative approach could then

1. use the `include_boundaries` parameter of [`pl.DataFrame.group_by_dynamic`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.group_by_dynamic.html) to add extra (temporary) group boundary columns to the dataframe (this will impact performance as it makes the operation harder to parallelize);
2. create an extra `last_date` column in the group aggregation to indicate the latest available date within each group;
3. filter for groups for which the last possible data row within the group exists (checked by comparing `last_date` with the date of the last possible data row within the group) or for which the "next group" exists (checked by verifying whether the upper boundary of the group is also lower boundary of another group).

**Implementation.**

```py
df_5 = (
    df_1
    .group_by_dynamic('date', every='5m', include_boundaries=True)
    .agg(
        pl.col('date').last().alias("last_date"),
        pl.col('open').first(),
        pl.col('close').last(),
    )
    .filter(
        (pl.col("last_date") == pl.col("date").dt.offset_by("4m")) | pl.col("_upper_boundary").is_in(pl.col("_lower_boundary"))
    )
    .drop(["_lower_boundary", "_upper_boundary", "last_date"])
)
```

Still, I am curious to see how alternative approaches could look like.

Comment: Thanks! I still intend to try this, but I have posted my answer below, as I hope it gives more clarity to what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: By doing include boundary, doesn't that give you a different last than intended? You could do a list method and get the 2nd to last though.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Can you elaborate a bit on your doubt? To me, it looks like the code above works as intended, but I am possibly missing an edge case.

Comment: I just double checked. My mistake, I thought include boundaries would change the close.last but it just includes an extra column.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this exhaustively, and it feels convulted, but I *think* it returns the results I am looking for. Hopefully, this better conveys what I am looking to achieve. To be honest, when I first asked the question, I truly thought I was simply missing a baked-in way to accomplish this (maybe I still am.) I hope this gives more clarity...

```
def _raw_downsample_df(df_1: pl.DataFrame, downsample_mins: int) -> pl.DataFrame:
    '''Downsample a 1 minute dataframe *without* concern
    for the completeness of the final period.'''

    return (
        df_1
        .group_by_dynamic('date', every=f'{downsample_mins}m')
        .agg(
            pl.col('open').first(),
            pl.col('close').last(),
            (pl.last("date") - pl.first("date")).dt.total_seconds().alias('diff'),
        )
    )

def _trim_raw_downsample_df(df_down: pl.DataFrame, downsample_mins: int) -> pl.DataFrame:
    '''Trim the final period of a downsampled dataframe,
    so that it only contains complete periods.
    
    .. note:: Returns None if no complete periods.
    '''

    expected_diff = 60 * (downsample_mins - 1)
    final_diff = df_down.tail(1).select('diff').item()
    df_down = df_down.drop('diff')

    if final_diff < expected_diff:

        if len(df_down) == 1:
            return
        
        return df_down.slice(0, -1)
    
    return df_down

def downsample_df(df_1: pl.DataFrame, downsample_mins: int) -> pl.DataFrame:
    '''Downsample a 1 minute dataframe.
    
    * Trims *last* downsampled period **if** it does not contain complete periods.
    * Returns None if there are no complete periods.
    '''

    df_down = _raw_downsample_df(df_1, downsample_mins)    
    return _trim_raw_downsample_df(df_down, downsample_mins)

downsample_df(df_1, 5)
```

Comment: With inputs `07:00, 07:10, 07:30, 07:50` this returns: `07:00`, `07:10`, `07:30` - is this intended? If I understand the description correctly, the result would be "empty" for this case?

Comment: Yes, it would be correct. Those 3 5-minute periods all definitely consist of only 1-minute's worth of data, so they could be finalized. There is nothing in 07:40, for example, so that is correctly not a 5-minute period at all. 07:50 is omitted because it is ambiguous as to whether there is more data to come within that period, and therefore, any aggregations on it might be erroneous. I would only want to generate it if it was followed by a period >= 07:54. group_by_dynamic mostly does exactly what I want, I just want to efficiently cap at the last definitely complete period.